# Testing a library in Node

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a library written for Node. It contains a bunch of code usable across multiple projects. I would like to write some tests for it, using Mocha, however I am unfamiliar with how to properly test it.

For example, code in one file in the project called `databaseManager.js` is exported as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  // properties
  connections: connections,
  // functions
  loadConnections: loadConnections,
  getDefaultConnection: getDefaultConnection,
  clearAllConnections: clearAllConnections
};
```

As you can predict, `loadConnections()` verifies and adds one or more Connections as once, which can then be reached via the `connections` property.

In my test file, I `require(databaseManager)`. But, for each `it` test, I'd like to have a "fresh" instance to test adding one or many good or bad configuration objects. However, the requiring caches the file, so that each test adds to the same "singleton" creating false positive errors.

For example:

```
describe('Database Manager Tests', function() {
    let singleValidConfig = {
      name: "postgresql.dspdb.postgres",
      alias: "pdp",
      dialect: "postgres", 
      database: "dspdb", 
      port: 5432, 
      host: "localhost", 
      user: "postgres", 
      password: "something",
      primary: false,
      debugLevel: 2 
    };

    it('load 1', function() {
      (function() { dbman.loadConnections(singleValidConfig, true); }).should.not.throw();
      console.log('load 1', dbman);
    });

    it('load 2', function() {
      let result = dbman.loadConnections(singleValidConfig, false);
      result.should.be.true;
      console.log('load 2', dbman);
    });
});
```

One will fail because they both add the same config to the one instance of `dbman`, which is guarded against. How do I make sure each `it` has a clean `connections` property?

Comment: You can use the hook `before` for setting up a testing environment. You can use one `before` function for each `describe` and also an `after` function for cleaning your testing environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern I see for this is instead of exporting a single object, export a factory function used to create unique instances. For example, when you `require('express')` that is a factory function which you can call how ever many times you need to spit out independent express application instances. You could do this along these lines:

```
// This is a function that works the same with or without the "new" keyword
function Manager () {
  if (!(this instanceof Manager)) {
    return new Manager()
  }
  this.connections = []
}

Manager.prototype.loadConnections = function loadConnections () {
  // this.connections = [array of connections]
}

Manager.prototype.getDefaultConnection = function getDefaultConnection () {
  // return this.defaultConnection
}
Manager.prototype.clearAllConnections = function clearAllConnections () {
  // this.connections = []
}

module.exports = Manager
```

To use this pattern:

```
const myManager = require('./db-manager')();
```